# KDE 5 notifications history

Tags: kde, notification, plasma-5

Any similar application or plasma widget to replace notifications on kde 5 ? 
The best notifications of linux world will never work anymore (KDE 4)
:(

Unity have a [indicator-notifications](https://launchpad.net/~jconti/+archive/recent-notifications), but it's not work on KDE !

Answer (score 2):

**Plasma 5.11 or later**

KDE Annoncements: https://www.kde.org/announcements/plasma-5.11.0.php

> Notification History
>
> Due to popular demand
>   notifications optionally stores missed and expired notifications in a
>   history. This is the first part of an ongoing effort to modernize the
>   notification system in Plasma. This allows the user to override
>   applications not marking their notifications as persistent, and
>   viewing what happened in her absence.

[image]

Comment: Has this ever seen the light of day ?

Answer (score 0):

I made an applet that keep all the notifications based on the current one, awaiting KDE 5.11 to become stable and widely distributed

https://store.kde.org/p/1227099/

Answer (score 0):

There is a widget which does this for you, it's called Notifications.

To add it right-click your panel, then click Add Widgets..., from there choose the Notifications widget with the bell icon. Once you've added it, left-click it to see the notifications history.

There's a chance that you already have the widget active, found under Show Hidden Icons (arrow icon).